# Изменение UILable с помощью UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 200, 20))
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
label.text = "lable"
self.view.addSubview(label)

let btn = UIButton(frame : CGRectMake(x, y , widthButton, heigthButton))

btn.setTitle((dicts["title"]), forState: .Normal)
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
btn.addTarget(self, action: "press:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
btn.tag = tag

self.view.addSubview(btn)


func press (sender: AnyObject) {

    if flag == true {

        sender.setTitle("player1", forState: .Normal)
        flag = false
    } else {
        sender.setTitle("player2", forState: .Normal)
        flag = true
    }

}
```

Как реализовать функцию чтобы менялась lable а не button? если писать lable.text то в функции это не доступно, обьявление в методе viewDidLoad, в чем я ошибся?

Comment: вам надо иметь референс на label в своем классе, и использовать self.label вместо sender (sender это референс на кнопку, которая вызывает вашу функция press)

Comment: так надо именно нажатием кнопки поменять, можете пример показать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var label:UILabel!
    var btn:UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 200, 20))
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        label.text = "lable"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        let btn = UIButton(frame : CGRectMake(0, 100 , 100, 44))

        btn.setTitle("title", forState: .Normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "press:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }

    func press (sender: AnyObject) {

        label.text = "text";
    }
}
```

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: в функции заменил lable.setTitle на lable.text =

Comment: не заметил, когда менял

Comment: исправил ответ.

Comment: так если сделать. то работает. странно как-то. у меня циклом делается куча кнопок, названия которых берутся из массива, состоящего из дикшенри. дебагером прошелся, затык на lable.text функция его как-то некорректно видит(хотя, если делать изменения кнопок - работает), возможно баг) делал так же через сторибоард тоже все ок. спасибо!

Comment: ну если подошло то принимайте ответ

Comment: так принят же)))

Comment: может не обновилась страница. сейчас вижу